# When I added new data , I want to view top of the List . How can I do it?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating new app with using sqlite in android . When I added new data , I wanna view top of the List on RecyclerView. I have `DatabaseHelper` class. I have `showData` function in `DatabaseHelper` class.

```
Cursor showData() {
       String query = "SELECT *FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

       Cursor c = null;
       if (db != null) {
           c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
       }
       return c;
   }
```

and I have `DisplayData` function in MainActivity.

```
void DisplayData(){
        Cursor c = db.showData();
        if(c.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Not Found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                lessonId.add(c.getString(0));
                lessonName.add(c.getString(1));
                lessonSubject.add(c.getString(2));
                solvedProblemCount.add(c.getString(3));
            }
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

[image]

How can i do it ?

Comment: Post the CREATE statement of your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `DisplayData` in `MainActivity.class` this way

```
void DisplayData(){
        Cursor c = db.showData();
        if(c.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Not Found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            noData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            c.moveToLast();
            c.moveToNext();
            while (c.moveToPrevious()) {
                lessonId.add(c.getString(0));
                lessonName.add(c.getString(1));
                lessonSubject.add(c.getString(2));
                solvedProblemCount.add(c.getString(3));
            }
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

and solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this to get list from DB in a sorted order. You can add a field in the table called lastUpdated and apply desc sort to that field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `ArrayList`, use this before displaying data...

```
                Collections.reverse(lessonId);
                Collections.reverse(lessonName);
                Collections.reverse(lessonSubject);
                Collections.reverse(solvedProblemCount);
```

**Note: Try to use an `Object` including all the fields(like `lessonId`,`lessonName`,`lessonSubject`,`solvedProblemCount`) and use an `ArrayList` for them...**